# How to cluster and visualize 3D data in python

Tags: python, clustering, visualization

I have a 3D dataset of x,y,z points with 2 categories, category A and B. My end goal is to cluster all points in category B into volumes (spheroids/clouds) and find all points of category A close to edge of those volumes. I assume there won't be any points of category A inside the spheroids. The points of category B are very highly clustered in space, so clusters are probably very evident.

In 2D GIS I have used Kernel Density Estimation and K-Means clustering for similar tasks, but since I am dealing with 3D data, and non-geographic at that (relative to a fictional 0,0,0 origin), and since I am comfortable with the python data science tools, I think matplotlib/scipy/numpy/sklearn/pandas/etc are probably better tools for this. But I am not sure what tools and libraries specifically would be good to look at.

So my question is 2-fold:

1. what libraries would be well suited to find the 3D clusters and the points of category A "close" to them
2. what tool would allow me to visualize the clusters, preferably in an interactive plot that allows me to zoom/pan/rotate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [answer by edmund](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/79941/how-to-cluster-and-visualize-3d-data-in-python/80911#80424) is quite cool because it shows the algorithms and methodology that I need, but unfortunately his answer was about the wolfram language that I don't know and I don't really want to learn a new language right now. But some digging and googling has turned up some good alternatives.
Specifically [Open3D](http://www.open3d.org/docs) and [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/) became my tools of choice. Sklean's [DBScan algorithm](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) is what I need for the clustering, and sklearn has a lot of other clustering algorithms as well.

Open3D is focused more on the geometric side of things and the visualization. It can create and visualize [point clouds](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/Basic/pointcloud.html) and [meshes](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/Basic/mesh.html), and also includes some data processing algorithms like dbscan and importantly Convex Hull, which allows me to turn my clustered pointclouds into meshes. It is not as strong on the data science side as sklean, but the combination of the two is really powerful, especially since open3d can create a pointcloud from a numpy array, and hence a pandas dataframe.

As a bonus I discovered [Three.js](https://threejs.org/) as well, which is great if you want to visualize your results on the web. It has really good visualization tools, camera control, interactivity, etc. And it performs very well due to its WebGL implementation, much better than I expected. Unfortunately the docs are quite limited. They seem to rely mostly on examples, which often contain a lot of cool functionality, but make it hard to isolate the specific information you need. But with some time investment and trial and error, you can take the files you produced with pandas/sklearn/open3d and show them on the web to users.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps is one method to achieve your result. I used [Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/) but the method can be applied by any language with the right libraries.

1. [`FindClusters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindClusters.html)
   for category A data (`dataA`),
2. calculate the
   [`ConvexHullMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh.html)
   for each of these clusters,
3. for each point in category B (`dataB`)
   calculate the
   [`RegionDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDistance.html)
   to each of the category A hulls,
4. and
   [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html) the
   `dataB` points by their nearest category A hull.

We can collect related 3D example data from [`"AdministrativeDivision"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/entity/AdministrativeDivision.html) [`Entity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entity.html) object properties.

```
dataA =
  Select[FreeQ[_Missing]]@
   EntityValue[
    EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision", {"ParentRegion" -> Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"]}]
    , {"GiniIndex", "TotalVotingRate", "HomeOwnershipRate"}];
First@dataA
```

> ```
> {0.4776, 56.3712%, 70.7%}
> ```

I used `FindClusters` with the [`"MeanShift"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/method/MeanShift.html) method to cluster. Two clusters were found.

```
clusters = FindClusters[dataA, Method -> "MeanShift"];
Length@clusters
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

The list of `ConvexHullMesh` for each cluster is obtained by

```
hulls = ConvexHullMesh /@ clusters
```

> [image]

These can be visualised with their internal points by combining a[`ListPointPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPointPlot3D.html) of `clusters` with a [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html) of `hulls` (with low [`Opacity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Opacity.html) to make them transparent) with [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html).

```
cp =
 Show[
  ListPointPlot3D[
   clusters
   , PlotStyle -> ColorData[110]
   , PlotTheme -> {"Web", "FrameGrid"}
   , BoxRatios -> Automatic]
  , Graphics3D[
     {Opacity[.1]
     , MapIndexed[
       {ColorData[110] @@ #2, EdgeForm[{Thin, Opacity[.1], ColorData[110] @@ #2}], #1} &
       , hulls]}]
  ]
```

> [image]

For category B example data we need points outside of the hulls of the clusters. We can create a [`Cuboid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cuboid.html) around the [`RegionUnion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionUnion.html) of `hulls` and hollow out the volume of `hulls` by taking the [`RegionDifference`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDifference.html). This region can be visualised with [`RegionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html).

```
With[
  {ru = RegionUnion[hulls]}
  , rd =
   RegionDifference[
    Cuboid @@ Transpose[
      MapAt[Ceiling[#, 0.01] &, {All, 2}]@
       MapAt[Floor[#, 0.01] &, {All, 1}]@
        RegionBounds@ru]
    , ru]
  ];
RegionPlot3D[rd
 , PlotStyle -> Opacity[.1]
 , Axes -> True]
```

> [image]

Then we can generate [`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html)s inside this region for `dataB`.

```
SeedRandom[19283745]
dataB = RandomPoint[DiscretizeRegion@rd, 20];
```

The `dataB` points can be combined with the `dataA` cluster plot with `Show`.  All of the `dataB` points are outside of the `dataA` hulls.

```
Show[
 cp
 , ListPointPlot3D[dataB
  , PlotStyle -> Black]
 ]
```

> [image]

Now that we have example category B data (`dataB`) we can calculate the [`RegionDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDistance.html) of each point to each of category A's `hulls`. Then by [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ordering.html) these distances the [`First`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html) entry gives the hull the point is closest to.

```
nc =
 First /@
  Ordering /@
   Transpose@
    Through[
     Function[r, RegionDistance[r, #] &, Listable][hulls][dataB]
     ]
```

> ```
> {2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1}
> ```

Lastly we `Pick` the `dataB` points by their closest hull and combine their plot with the `dataA` cluster plot with `Show`. `dataB` points have been coloured to indicate their closest `dataA` cluster.

```
pncB = Pick[dataB, nc, #] & /@ Range@Length@hulls;

Show[
 cp
 , ListPointPlot3D[
  pncB
  , PlotStyle -> ColorData[104]
  , BoxRatios -> Automatic
  ]
 ]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it looks pretty cool. Maybe my question wasn't great for a data science site since I could expect science focused answer like yours. I did state though that I am comfortable in python data science tools, and was asking for specific libraries/pacakges in that area. Learning a fully new language isn't an option right now.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is linear in nature, you might want to look into PCA. It is a simple method that allows to visualize the data after transforming it into fewer dimensions:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html

Comment: I am not doing multivariate analysis. I am literally talking about 3Dimensional data in space. I don't want to reduce the number of dimensions. I want to find the clusters of points and visualize those. It is spatial data. Just not related to a surface like the earth, which is what GIS software assumes.